# R INSTALL ON SERVER ERROR "bzip2 library and headers are required" despite being already installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, r, rstudio, bzip2

I keep getting the error

> checking whether bzip2 support suffices... configure: error: bzip2 library and headers are required

when trying to install R onto a server environment. I installed bzip2 already to my packages folder and I also installed it into my home directory using `make install PREFIX=/gpfs/ts0/home/mya205/`, but it seems that R installation on the server still can't find bzip and displays the error above.

Any ideas?

EDIT: If anyone else has insufficient privileges on your platform, you can install R through conda

Comment: We would use, as usual, the same cliché that we have been already using maybe four or five times on this Web-Site: _you need an_ `R` _Expert to help you troubleshoot this Issue_. However, as usual, the Issue might not be related to the `R` Statistical Programming Language at all. In your case, it is definitely related to the `bzip2` Archiving Software Utility, @Yaseen Ahammed. It is not necessary to install it two times. You just have to make sure that the `PATH` Operating System Environment Variable reaches it. Can you please inspect it and show it to us, so that we can further investigate?

Comment: Can you please tell us what does the `echo $PATH` Operating System Command output?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the **development** package of the `bzip2` compressor:

```sh
sudo apt/yum install libbz2-dev
```